# Dice in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a dice simulator where program asks how many dices are in game.
And would like to use while command.

My beginning is

```
from random import randint 

dice_input = int(input("Enter how many dices you have: ")
dice_rand = randint(1,6)
i = 1
while i < dice_input:
    print(dice)
```

The outcome would be, if user inputs 5 then there would be 5 random numbers

It would be very good if somebody would help me out with this easy thing

Comment: One problem you'll immediately run into is that your while loop will never terminate. Do you understand why this problem will occur?

Comment: Also, it might be easier with a `for` loop where you don't have to worry about accidentally creating an infinite loop: `for i in range(dice_input): # (roll dice)`.

Comment: I understand this, but I have tried different variations but then there would be just one randint answer. My question would be, how I could just get the program running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should increment `i` in the `while` loop so that the terminal condition can be reached. Also, `i` should start from `0` instead, and you should put `randint(1,6)` inside the loop so that it can draw a new number for each iteration:

```
from random import randint    
dice_input = int(input("Enter how many dices you have: "))
i = 0
while i < dice_input:
    print(randint(1,6))
    i += 1
```